# Golang gRPC database serialization key format defined on struct

Tags: go, serialization, struct, grpc

I want to use the go structs that are generated by the gRPC compiler directly for database transactions but the problem is that only the `json` serialization field is set by gRPC.

Is there a way to either set additional serialization keys (like shown below) or is there another golang specific way to tell the database driver (`sqlx` on top of `database/sql`) that the `json` key format should be used?

Some example - The gRPC compiler creates the following struct:

```
type HelloWorld struct {
  TraceId string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=trace_id,json=traceId,proto3" json:"trace_id,omitempty"`
...
```

What I would like to have:

```
type HelloWorld struct {
  TraceId string `db:"trace_id" protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=trace_id,json=traceId,proto3" json:"trace_id,omitempty"`
...
```

A temporary workaround would be to write sql queries that use aliases (`traceid` instead of `trace_id` in this example) but it doesn't feel consistent and adds a lot of complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that currently there is no built-in way of doing this. However, you might be interested in following this thread: https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/52

Other than that I think you can just create yet another struct for database access and make the mapping explicit which might be more readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. The idea using sed is the best workaround imho: `sed -E 's/json:("[^"]+,omitempty")/json:\1 db:\1/g'`

Comment: Also, the article was interesting because of `gogoprotobuf` which is definitely worth looking at especially if one is only using golang and no other languages.